# How to install Subversion in Red Hat Developer Studio 12.9.0.GA?

Tags: redhat, jboss-developer-studio

Wondering how to install SVN perspective in Red Hat Developer Studio 12.9.0.GA

Please note I'm using OpenJDK 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that OpenJDK 1.8 and Red Hat Developer Studio 12.9.0.GA should not be any problem here, although I would suggest you to get the newest [Red Hat CodeReady Studio 12.11.0.GA](https://developers.redhat.com/products/codeready-studio/download/).

Open the IDE, by default, you should see Red Hat Central page in the middle, if not, you can open it clicking on the Red Hat Central icon in the toolbar or in menu find Help -> Red Hat Central. Switch the tab in the page to Software/update and search for "svn" string, you should see Subclipse + SVNKit option (and another item with mylyn integration), choose it, install it, restart. Then you should be able to open the perspective: Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Others... -> SVN Repository Exploring.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to IntelliJ. I find Eclipse-based IDE's are terrible, in terms of performance and usability. I think it's time to retire them.